# CoreData throws exception with NSUndoManager

Tags: ios, core-data, nsundomanager

I have an iPad app where I am using the NSUndoManager with Core Data. Things usually work well, except that there is a semi-reproducible bug when I undo/redo several times. I am only working on the main thread (at least, I have disabled MagicalRecords from using an NSManagedObject on a secondary thread. The problem always occurs if I try to undo/redo an insertion of an NSManagedObject to the context.

So I have something like this:

```
if (!self.undoManager.isUndoing && !self.undoManager.isRedoing) 
{
    [self.undoManager undo];   
}
else 
{
    NSLog(@"gotcha!");
}
```

And after several times, I get the following exception. It happens on a secondary thread, which makes me think Core Data is doing something in the background.

```
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  Exception was caught during Core Data
change processing.  This is usually a bug within an observer of 
NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification.  _registerUndoObject:: NSUndoManager 
0xcea2d60 is in invalid state, must begin a group before registering undo
with userInfo (null) 2012-07-25 15:42:26.850 TT[3972:3c07] *** Terminating app due to 
uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '_registerUndoObject::
NSUndoManager 0xcea2d60 is in invalid state, must begin a group before registering undo
```

Sometimes I am also getting EXEC_BAD_ACCESS, other times just the exception above.

Any idea what could be causing this?

Edit: clarified situation for Mundi (see comments)

Comment: You need to give more context than just the call to `undo`.

Comment: When the undo occurs, I rebuild the UI, which is quite an expensive operation (rebuilding a lot of custom UIViews from the original NSManagedObjects). This eventually will be optimized. It would be hard to provide a snipped of code here (it's a large project) -- what would be useful for you?

Comment: I am undoing the insertion of an NSManagedObject. That seems to be one of the situations where the crashing occurs most often

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution that stopped all my crashes:
Apparently Magical Records uses privateQueue concurrency by default, and if your code isn't that thread safe, I guess things don't work out. What I did is change it from  NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType to NSMainQueueConcurrencyType for the following method:

```
+ (NSManagedObjectContext *) MR_contextWithoutParent;
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [[self alloc] initWithConcurrencyType:NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType];
return context;
}
```

I also found another detail that worked here:
[Core Data deleteObject: sets attributes to nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2968063/core-data-deleteobject-sets-attributes-to-nil)

What I had to do was save the managed object context before adding/deleting a managed object. Kind of weird and inefficient, but saves lots of trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Standard way to undo the insertion of a managed object is

```
[self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:theManagedObject];
// If you have saved already, you would need to save again.
```

No need to use the undo mechanism. Like this, you code becomes

- much **more readable** (you are saying explicitly what you want to do) and
- much **less error prone** (no unforeseen events with more complex APIs).

Comment: If I am using an undo manager for the rest of my undo actions, how would you intercept a delete operation and then handle that custom? It seems like I would have to keep track of my own undo/redo stack

Comment: Alright, I misunderstood what you were doing. How about, in the "gotcha!" part, you just dispatch the undo on another thread?

Comment: It seems to never hit the gotcha part anymore. I am trying to figure out a good way to know when Core Data is done processing stuff. I tried calling processChanges before undoing, but that doesn't seem to help. I even tried doing a performSelect:withDelay:0 to skip to the next run loop in the case where the undoManager is currently undoing/redoing:

if (self.undoManager.isUndoing || self.undoManager.isRedoing)
    {
        NSLog(@"issue here! skipping");
        [self performSelector:@selector(didRedoChange:) withObject:notification afterDelay:0];
    }

Comment: I have a feeling this doesn't occur with the normal shake gestures because that gives the device enough time to process everything. THe only thing that seems to fix it (though kind of a hack) is to disable the undo/redo buttons for 1/2 second to prevent successive taps.

Comment: I am having this issue now after undoing an insertion.